# Convert type "char**" to "const char**"

Tags: c++, casting, program-entry-point

The following code can't compile:

```
  char** s;
  const char** s2 = s;
```

I know the followings can work but I think there should be some better legitimate way to do it?

```
  long long x = reinterpret_cast<long long>(s);
  s2 = reinterpret_cast<const char**>(x);
```

The background of this question is, I want to use two libraries which have 
functions handling argc/argv with different signatures:

```
void Init1(int argc, char** argv);
void Init2(int argc, const char** argv);
```

Then what's the best way to define my signature of main to call both of those two functions?

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you can add or remove `const`-ness through [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast), eg:

```
char** s;
const char** t = const_cast<const char**>(s);
```

Since you are dealing with argv it should be quite safe to add const-ness to them as long as the `Init2` doesn't try to alter anything, and it shouldn't since its argument is `const char**`.

Mind that attepting to modify the value of a variable that was `const` after removing the cv qualifier leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: The problem with this conversion would not be with `Init2` trying to modify const characters (which it can't do without a cast), it is with it setting the `const char*` to point to the address of an actual `const char`, and then, for example, `Init1` trying to modify the characters at that address, which as far as it knows it should be perfectly safe to do, since its argument is `char**`. So no, this isn't safe. That's why the compiler complains.